# How to call Meteor.call inside a react component on the client?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

My error always return `undefined` whenever I call the `Meteor.Call` function in a React Template inside the client folder.

This is my code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendLogMessage: function(){
    return "Hello World";
  }
});
```

and this is the call from my jsx file:

```
console.log(Meteor.call('sendLogMessage'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Meteor calls on the client are asynchronous.

Use a callback:

```
Meteor.call('sendLogMessage', function (error, result) {
  console.log(result); //logs "Hello World"
});
```